# Change HTML data based of AJAX JSON Results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having some trouble with an issue I'm working on.  Basically if someone clicks on a link with a list of offices, it will make an AJAX call to a file which queries the DB and returns the results in a JSON object.  At this point it needs to take those values and loop through HTML and apply those values accordingly.  What I can't figure out is exactly how to make that loop.  I'm hitting a wall so to speak.  This is in Wordpress and using a plugin called PODS.

**The HTML**

```
<?php
    $staff = new Pod('staff');
    $staff->findRecords('name ASC');
    $total_staff = $staff->getTotalRows();
?>

<?php if( $total_staff>0 ) : ?>

    <div class="twelve">
        <div class="team-title">Corporate Office</div>
    </div>
    <div id="team-photo-container">
    <?php while ( $staff->fetchRecord() ) : ?>
            <?php

                $staff_id        = $staff->get_field('id');
                $staff_name      = $staff->get_field('name');
                $staff_title     = $staff->get_field('staff_title');
                $staff_bio       = $staff->get_field('staff_bio');
                $staff_fav_apps  = $staff->get_field('staff_favorite_apps');
                $staff_office    = $staff->get_field('staff_office');
                $staff_pic       = $staff->field('staff_pic.guid');
                $staff_slug      = $staff->get_field('permalink');
            ?>
            <div class="packery">
                <div class="team-img">
                    <div class="imgs">
                        <img class="team-photo" src="<?php echo $staff_pic; ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="img-info">
                            <div class="mem-name"><?php echo $staff_name; ?></div>
                            <div class="mem-title"><?php echo $staff_title; ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ind-bio">
                            <div class="twelve columns btns">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self" class="read-more close">
                                            <span>
                                                <i class="foundicongen-remove"></i>Close
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self" class="read-more">
                                            <span>
                                                <i class="foundicon-plus"></i>Share 
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="team-member-name"><?php echo $staff_name; ?></h3>
                            <h5 class="team-member-title"><?php echo $staff_title; ?></h5>
                            <p><?php echo $staff_bio; ?></p>
                            <div class="twelve">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self" class="read-more">
                                            <span>
                                                <i class="foundiconsoc-youtube"></i>Watch Video
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twelve favorites team-title">
                                <span>Favorite Apps:</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self">
                                            <span>
                                                <?php echo $staff_fav_apps; ?>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile ?>
            <?php endif ?>
```

**The PHP/SQL**

```
<?php
    $office = $_GET['office'];

    $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Could not connect");

    mysql_select_db("database") or die("Could not select database");

    $arr = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT name, staff_title, staff_bio, staff_favorite_apps, staff_office FROM table WHERE staff_office ='" . $office . "'");

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) 
    {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }

    echo '{"members":'. json_encode($arr). '}';

    ?>
```

**The jQuery/AJAX**

```
$('.category-submenu li').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/load-team.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {office: $(this).data('office')},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#team-photo-container').html("<div class='loader'><img src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></div>");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.team-title').html(data['members'][0]['staff_office'] + ' Office');
                $.each( data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#team-photo-container').html();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Now when checking the Results, I get the json object like this:

```
{"members":[{
             "name":"Bruce Willis",
             "staff_title":"Title Here",
             "staff_bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
             "staff_favorite_apps":"ZULILY, INSTAGRAM, PBA CHALLENGE",
             "staff_office":"City"
            },
            {
             "name":"Bruce Jenner",
             "staff_title":"Title Here",
             "staff_bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
             "staff_favorite_apps":"ZULILY, INSTAGRAM, PBA CHALLENGE",
             "staff_office":"City"
            }]
           }
```

As you can see if I have 5 people in one office but only 3 in another I need to remove the 5 and replace them with the 3 while either generating the html on the fly or replacing the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: Is the HTML class "packery" the container for all results and the class "team-img" the container for each individual?

Comment: team-photo-container is for all results and packery is for each result (i.e. each image of the person and bio information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this format to remove your existing HTML and generate the replacement HTML:

```
var something = [{
             "name":"Bruce Willis",
             "staff_title":"Title Here",
             "staff_bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
             "staff_favorite_apps":"ZULILY, INSTAGRAM, PBA CHALLENGE",
             "staff_office":"City"
            },
           {
             "name":"Bruce Jenner",
             "staff_title":"Title Here",
             "staff_bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
             "staff_favorite_apps":"ZULILY, INSTAGRAM, PBA CHALLENGE",
             "staff_office":"City"
           }];

$(".team-photo-container").html("");
for(var key in something){
    $(".team-photo-container").append("<div class = 'packery'></div>");
    $(".packery:last").append("<div>" + something[key]["name"] + "</div>");
    //add the rest of the inner DIVs
}
```

As you can see, there is quite a bit of JavaScript that you'll have to write to generate the inner DIVs.  There is an alternative method to this.  Instead of sending JSON values through the AJAX request, you can send the compiled HTML through the request.  You'll be able to reuse most of the PHP / HTML from your original page on the AJAX page.  There'll be more data transferred through the AJAX request, but you'll have a much more clean view sheet since the HTML would be compiled on your AJAX page.  You can then use the following on success callback to reload your "team-photo-container" DIV:

```
success: function(data) {
                $(".team-photo-container").html(data);
            }
```

Comment: wow thanks for the insight and detailed example.  I will work on implementing this today and let you know what I come up with.  Thanks

Comment: When adding this, var members = data; for (var i in members) { console.log('index is ' + i + ' and data is ' + members[i]); $("#team-photo-container").append("<div class='packery'></div>"); $(".packery:last").append("<div>" + members[i] + "</div>"); }...I get this index is members and data is [object Object],[object Object]...it appears as though it's not getting the correct data, what am I missing?

Comment: @JoshChristensen Change $("#team-photo-container") to $(".team-photo-container").  Also change members[i] to members[i]["name"]

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I did it exactly like you suggested the first time and it gave me this, index is members and data is undefined, which led me to believe that in the success function when I start my loop, without specifying data['members'][0]['staff_office'] it can't get the value, but I could be mistaken.